# In Matlab patch plot, can I recolour a specific face of the polyhedron?

Tags: matlab, plot, patch

I want to recolour a specific face (say the first) in the following patch plot so it has a different colour from all the other faces. Here's the code for the polyhedron:

```
clear;
faces = [1     3     5
         2     4     6
         1     3     6
         2     4     5
         1     4     5
         2     3     6
         1     4     6
         2     3     5];

vert = [8.6288   -1.4930    0.1330
       -8.6288    1.4930   -0.1330
       -1.6879   -4.9352   -6.3458
        1.6879    4.9352    6.3458
        2.9250    7.1153   -4.6262
       -2.9250   -7.1153    4.6262];

clf
axes();
xlabel('x');
ylabel('y');
zlabel('z');
patch('vertices',vert,'faces',faces, 'facecolor','blue', 'facealpha', 0.4);
```

And the patch plot it gives:

[image]

Unfortunately, due to lack of working examples of color map provided in the [`patch properties`](https://cn.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.primitive.patch-properties.html) documentation, I really have no idea how to do it.

Could anybody help me? Thanks!

Comment: The easiest, but probably not the cleanest solution, is drawing each face separately (i.e. call `patch` multiple times) - which allows you to choose the color. Otherwise, I'd try to `findall` `patch`, and assuming you'll get back several of those, figure out which one you need to change.

Comment: @Dev-iL I'm already aware of which one I need to recolour so don't have to "figure it out".

Comment: I said "figure out" because I don't know in what order they'll be returned...

Comment: @Dev-iL thanks. But my idea was: use a `hold on`, then use some function to just fill the specific triangle in the space (totally independent from the previous patch), provided such a function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hold on
faces2 = [1     3     5]; % the face you want to recolor
patch('vertices',vert,'faces',faces2, 'facecolor','red', 'facealpha', 0.4);
```

[image]

Comment: I'd advise that the chosen face is removed from `faces`. Plotting several faces in the exact same place might cause graphical glitches when viewing the figure.

Comment: You are right, in previous plot (red+blue) was shown as purple.